# Как хранить секретный json файл в android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть мобильное приложение,  в нем json файлик который не должен быть доступен в ресурсах каждому кто распаковал apk как архив. В swift я это решил положив json в виде строки в свойство и это отлично работает.

```
var json = “””
    {“key”: [“value1”, "value2"]}
“””
```

В котлине я получил ошибку

```
 “Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated for static initializer”
```

Оказалось что переменная при инициализации не может быть больше 80 кб.

Как бы вы решили проблему хранения секретного json на котлин/андройд?

Хранить файл в ресурсах в зашифрованном виде не подходит в силу того что этот json нужно часто редактировать. И каждый рад его шифровать с помощью сторонней утилиты будет не совсем удобно.

Comment: Ресурсы не редактируются  - вам по-любому придётся писать этот json в файл. Поэтому шифрование ресурса на сохранение в рантайме не влияет. С другой стороны сам файл будет доступен юзеру на рутированных устройствах - и его по-любому придётся шифровать, если этот факт вас не устраивает

Answer (score 2):

Для начала я бы смирился с тем, что вы не можете гарантировать сохранность данных, которые кладете в apk. Если действительно захотеть - все будет вытащено, т.к. нет и вряд ли в ближайшие годы будет возможность прятать хотя бы ключи шифрования. Вам остается только создавать для потенциальных злоумышленников такой уровень сложности задачи, чтобы ее тратить силы на ее решение стало нецелесообразно. Могу предложить следующий путь:

1. json шифруем. Можете сами покопаться с шифровкой байтовых массивов, можете просто засунуть файл в запароленный zip-архив. В android с ним работать весьма просто. Результат шифрования кладем в ресурсы, в assets или raw, например. Не забываем про соль
2. засовываете пароль/ключ в программу. Прячете всеми правдами и неправдами. Дробите на части, преобразуете побитовыми операторами, используете полиморфизм чтобы скрыть получение данных
3. используете proguard, хотя бы на стандартной конфигурации

Этого уже достаточно, чтобы заставить человека, пытающегося что-то вытащить из вашей программы, сдаться на первых шагах. Правда если на первых шагах он не сдастся, то рано или поздно все равно разберется что к чему и увидит ваш json.

Это, так скажем, программа минимум. Есть еще способы сокрытия, но их предпочитают не особо разглашать, т.к. если способ становится общеизвестным - он перестает работать

PS Со swift я не работал и не знаю как там устроено хранение ресурсов, но не вижу причин думать, что там хранение секретных данных в зашитых строках более безопасно, чем в kotlin/java. Сохранили строку в виде литерала = сделали ее легкодоступной

Answer (score 0):

1) Поспорю с предыдущим оратором @СпицкоДмитрий. Конечно же, есть способ шифрования сложно вскрываемый. В качестве ключа шифрования можно использовать идентификатор [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) - естественно обложившись солью и проч. прибамбасами.

2) Не очень понимаю ТС, который утверждает:

> Хранить файл в ресурсах в зашифрованном виде не подходит в силу того что этот json нужно часто редактировать. И каждый рад его шифровать с помощью сторонней утилиты будет не совсем удобно.

Что тут неудобного то? Упакуйте шифрование/дешифровку в отдельный класс, который абстрагирует разработчика от способа хранения/представления - всего то делов.

3) Если ТС продолжает настаивать на способе *а ля Swift* - то и здесь не вижу препятствий:

-- Разбиваете исходный `Json` на несколько `String`, размер каждого из которых менее 64kb

-- Далее перед применением цепляете все эти строчки через `StringBuilder` формируете конечный длинный `String`, типа:

```
static String res1="blah-blah1";
static String res2="blah-blah2";
static String res3="blah-blah3";

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

String jsonString=sb.append(res1).append(res2).append(res3).toString();
```

Comment: Интересно как можно задействовать `ANDROID_ID` в расшифровке ресурса, который надо упаковать на этапе сборки уже шифрованным?

Comment: элементарно Ватсон: засовываем наш Json (нешифрованный) в `expansion file`. Далее при первом запуске приложения вытаскиваем Json из `obb` (expansion) файла шифруем его с помощью `ANDROID_ID` и кладем его либо в `SharedPreference` или в `SQLite`, OBB файл с нешифрованным Json удаляем. Все.

Comment: А в чем спор в 1 пункте? Существует абсолютно невскрываемые "ящики"?

Comment: Хороший аргумент, еще квантовые вычисления приведите как пример :)