# Как максимально просто зашифровать и расшифровать переменную String?

Tags: java, android

Чтобы  непонятно было куда идет ссылка !

```
public String loadUrl="https://---";
```

Comment: Вообще не хранить литералов, собирать их каким-нить замудрёным выражением прямо в момент использования.

Comment: А смысл? Если код для расшифровки будет тут же рядом, то какой символ шифровать?

Comment: Ну а как тогда сделать чтобы никто не увидел ссылку!?

Comment: Доменное имя и IP адрес сервера в любом случае не проблема узнать, достаточно посмотреть DNS запрос. Супер секретного способа хранения строковых переменных нет. Посмотрите эту [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570989)

Comment: Можете привести пример нежелательного сценария при котором ссылка будет не скрыта? Как именно этой информацией может воспользоваться "злоумышленник"? От этого зависит предложенное решение. Просто так надежно такую информацию не скрыть. Если человеку сильно понадобится, он этот адрес получит. Вопрос во времени. за 10 минут или за 20.

Answer (score 0):

Я отвечал на подобный вопрос [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1047978/335938). Но в вашем случае вы хотите прятать заведомо публичную вещь - общедоступный доменный адрес. Я почти уверен, что что-то с точки зрения безопасности вы делаете не так. Если вы прячете просто домен - это абсолютно бессмысленно, элементарнейший снифер на роутере, к которому подключен пользователь, перехватит DNS запрос и выдаст ваш домен, как бы вы его не прятали. Если в ссылке упоминаются файлы, передаются данные аки get запрос, или еще чего - вы что-то делаете не так. Если уточните что именно в ссылке не должно попасть недругу на глаза - может смогу что-то более дельное предложить