# Как зашифровать string в java без ключей любыми способами?

Tags: java, android, криптография

Как зашифровать string в  java без ключей  любыми способами !

```
String url= "https://Text";
```

Comment: Можете перевести в кодировку base64 - не шифрование, но зато человеко-не-читаемое. Ну или посчитайте от нее хэш любым методом

Comment: @cauf, хэш не является шифрованием. После хэша строку не восстановить. Роман, можно xor'ом пройтись или цезарем, но это все фигня :)

Comment: @gil9red нам ничего не известно о целях автора. Если есть потребность восстановления, то надо было обозначить. Я исходил из потребности обфускации значения

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как максимально просто зашифровать и расшифровать переменную String?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149434/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-string)

Comment: @cauf, обфускация изменит данные, но сохранит их функциональность, а после хэширование не восстановить их :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой способ. Можно взять какую-нибудь вариацию алгоритма [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) - по сути это способ шифрования не ключом, а алгоритмом. ROT13 проще показать, чем объяснять:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно колется за 2 секунды, но...

Answer (score 0):

Если без ключей, то никак. Можете попробовать попрятать саму строку в подробленном виде, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1047978/335938) я писал как. Переходите сразу к пункту 2